# How do I add comments to existing table DDL in Teradata?

Tags: ddl, teradata

I am adding some new columns to a table and want to add documentation to the table DDL for future developers.  How does one go about this?

Comment: imho not in the database itself - if a table is normalized, the column name should speak for itself mostly.

Comment: For reasons too complicated to explain, comments are definitely required for this new column.

Comment: 30 characters is often not always sufficient for describing the column. Comments do serve a purpose to help self-document the table or the columns. Plus these comments could later be extracted and loaded into an enterprise metadata manager or data dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Generic Syntax:**

```
COMMENT ON {OBJECT} {OBJECTNAME} AS '{255 characters of text};
```

**Detailed Syntax Examples:**

```
COMMENT ON TABLE {DATABASE}.{TABLENAME} AS '{255 characters of text}';
COMMENT ON COLUMN {DATABASENAME}.{TABLENAME}.{COLUMNNAME} AS '{255 characters of text}';
COMMENT ON USER {USERNAME} AS '{255 characters of text}';
COMMENT ON DATABASE {DATABASENAME} AS '{255 characters of text}';
```

Comment: I am just now getting back to this after a year and a half.  Forgot all about it until I needed it again.  Is there any way to view these comments other than querying the dbc views?  After adding a table comment, I expected it to show in `show table`.  I'd like it to be viewable in a conspicuous place for future developers.

Comment: SHOW TABLE simply reproduces the DDL for the current version of the table. If an object has a comment it will be displayed in the Database Explorer in Teradata's SQL Assistant as a Tooltip when the mouse is placed over the object's name. See Bob's example below for placing comments in the object definition that would display with the SHOW command.

Comment: Tooltip confirmed.  It's too bad that you have to know about this before you use it, though.  I foresee lots of confusion in the future with how I implemented bitwise unless they know to 1) query dbc.tables or 2) hover over the table in the SQLA explorer.

Comment: I would suggest that level of documentation belongs in your data dictionary more-so than along side your DDL. The comments in the database are are limited to 255 characters. Business rules or designer decisions are likely more verbose, hence the need for documentation in a proper data dictionary or metadata manager.

Comment: @RobPaller Is there a way to write a comment upon creation of the table. Smth like that: `create table tbname (col1 date comment 'elecday');` ? 

damn, I think is not(

Answer (score 3):

In addition to adding object COMMENTs, you can add in-line comments to view definitions.  Since most access is always through a view, that's how we communicate the DBA responsible for the table and document changes.  For example:

```
replace view VIEWDB.vmy_table as
locking DATADB.my_table for access
select *
from  DATADB.my_table
/* This is a comment */
/* Created by Bob */
```

The nice thing about this technique is that the comments are shown when you do a `SHOW SELECT * FROM VIEWDB.vmy_table`.