# Add/transfer CommentString to columns in TeraData using the CREATE TABLE AS SELECT statement

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I want to add desciptions to my columns that I can query in Teradata.

I recently came aware of the existence of the CommentString Column in TeraData DBC.Columns. I want to use it to add (short) descriptions to columns. Since I have a lot of code that is using the CREATE TABLE AS SELECT statement, I am ideally looking for a solution where I can keep my code as much as it is.

I tried something like:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (
  SELECT
    col1,
    col2 COMMENT 'This is a CommentString for col2'
  FROM
    source_table
) WITH DATA;
```

My desired result: the commentstring from col1 to be transferred from source_table to new_table and to add a new CommentString to col2

( I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834992/how-do-i-add-comments-to-existing-table-ddl-in-teradata) Question, where a seperate Statement is used with `COMMENT ON`. However that will give too much extra syntax for this project to be more readable. )

Comment: COMMENT ON is the only way to do this, no workaround.

Comment: As far as "transferring" comments: A stored procedure could be used to query DBC.ColumnsV.CommentString for the source table columns and build / execute COMMENT ON statements for corresponding target table columns. (You would need to pass the two table names as parameters in the CALL.) But CREATE TABLE AS does not transfer them automatically.